# How to Change the Font Size of the R Help Window in R Tools for Visual Studio (RTVS)?

Tags: visual-studio, rtvs

I am using the R Tools for Visual Studio (RTVS) IDE. I want to increase the font size in the R Help window. For example, if you have RTVS installed in your Visual Studio, loading "Data science settings" from the R Tools menu and entering `?mean()` into the R interactive console will bring up an R Help window displaying the R documentation for the `mean` function.

However, the font is too small. I know how to change the font size in other windows of the IDE:

> R Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors > Show Settings for:

But, unless I'm mistaken, I've tried every option in the "Show Settings for:" drop-down menu and none of them increased the font size in the R Help window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try `ctrl + scroll` wheel, that works fine for me. The `ctrl + "-/+"` once worked but it seems they are forbidden in the new version of RTVS.

Comment: Both `ctrl + scroll` and `ctrl + -/+/=` worked. Thanks!

Comment: @coip I‘m glad it helps. Actually that's one of the reasons that pushed me from RStudio to RTVS --  I can't set different fonts for the editor and help in RStudio!